# Given a number as input, tells its group

Tags: language-agnostic

Let's say we have several set of 4 numbers, alternating between two groups A & B.

So,

[image]

and the pattern continues.

Now I am trying to write a function that given a number as input, tells its group.

So given the number, say 3, returns "Group A". Similarly an input of say the number 14, returns "Group B".

A naive function in Python could look like:

```
def tell_group(num):
    A = [0,1,2,3,8,9,10,11]
    if num in A:
       return "Group A"
    else:
       return "Group B"
```

But this is not scalable.

I am not looking for any particular language implementation, rather the mathematical logic that would achieve this for any given number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the modulo operator `%` AKA `MOD`

```
if   num % (groupSize * 2) < groupSize  // is "Group A"
```

Or take it this way:

```
 0 MOD (4*2) < 4   // true
 3 MOD (4*2) < 4   // true 
 4 MOD (4*2) < 4   // false 
13 MOD (4*2) < 4   // false
```

Here's a JavaScript test case:

```js
function getGroup(num, groupSize) {

  let group;

  if ( num % (groupSize * 2) < groupSize) 
      group = "Group A";
  else
      group = "Group B";
   
  return group;
  
}

console.log( getGroup(0, 4) );
console.log( getGroup(3, 4) );
console.log( getGroup(4, 4) );
console.log( getGroup(13, 4) );
```

Notice that the above works only with `num` being a positive integer, otherwise the result will be `true`. In such cases you could either do a `if(num < 0) // handle error here;` or do some Math ABS...